# How to dynamically change ImageView Height

Tags: android, imageview

I have a simple linear layout used for ListView's cell, and it has an imageview. The image will be downloaded from internet, so the size can be different sizes.

However, I want to set the width of imageview to be fill_parent, which is fixed, and dynamically change the image height at runtime.  Rules to set the image height: 
if the image's h/w ratio is more than 1, make the ImageView square, means match the height to the width.

if the image's h/w ratio is less than 1, size it proportionally. Expected two samples as below.

The First one is h/w<1, while the second one 'Cat' is h/w>1.

[image]
[image]
Thanks for your time.

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy_image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/postImage"  />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

You will need to subclass ImageView

Override the onMeasure, I haven't tested this but all the variables you need are there and the idea is correct. You just perform the apply the aspect ratio of the image to the imageviews height, and if it's greater than the width, set it to the width.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
    if (drawable != null)
    {
        //get imageview width
        int width =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);


        int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int dih = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        float ratio = (float)diw/dih; //get image aspect ratio

        int height = width * ratio;

        //don't let height exceed width
        if (height > width){
            height = width;
        }


        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);    
    }
    else
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}
```

Comment: what happens, because those settings will scale the image such that the width is static and the height is pulled respective to the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: the xml i showed is for an adapter's getview, the ImageView dynamically load an image from url

Comment: actually I shall ask "how to get the actual px size for the fill_parent", I figured it out by using DisplayMetrics

Comment: To do what you are doing you really don't need to do that... Could you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Updated the question, please take a look. Thanks

Comment: So your real question is that you don't want the height to ever exceed the width (which is fixed to fill_parent)? So you want it to crop if it is too tall to fit?

Comment: Please see my answer, this takes care of the image sizing. You'll have to experiment with scaleType to get the image to look right in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

The place where you are loading the imageView in the code from the url, you have to set the layout parameters of the ImageView over there. It will change the dimensions of the image dynamically.

After loading the image find the dimensions and calculate the ratio and change the dimensions according to the condition you want to apply.

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    //set other properties of the imageview according to your condition
```

Comment: I have the the image size. So the problem, how can I know the what height to set for the ImageView? I did it through displaymetrics.widthPixels minus margins i set in xml layout(dp to px converted). Is this the best way? Thanks