# Dynamic ImageView Not visible Android (My code attached)

Tags: java, android, dynamic, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to dynamically creating imageview but it is not visible my code is:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MultiQuesRelaLayOut);

final ImageView[] im=new ImageView[10];
for(int img=0; img<2.length; img++)
{
    im[img]=new ImageView(this);   
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
         ((int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin=25;
    params.topMargin=(img+1)*(35+add);
    im[img].setId(img);
    im[img].layout(5,5,5,5);
    im[img].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    im[img].setBackgroundColor(color.background_dark);
    im[img].setPadding(5, 15, 5, 15);
    im[img].setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.addView(im[img]);
    im[img].setOnClickListener(ImageOnClick(im[img]));
}
```

How to view imageview on form by changnig it s background image or some thing like that ?

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: what is parent layout of all images means is it Linear or Relative ?

Comment: if the layout is relative, try to follow the answer here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004096/how-to-make-a-dynamic-imageview][1]

Comment: Lucia link you mention are creating image view from code behind i am creating at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the ImageView with this LayoutParams: **wrap_content, wrap_content**, but you have not add img to the ImageView, so, the content length **is 0 for height and width.**

Comment: how to add height and width for creating dynamic imageview

Comment: With wrap_content, the imageview set height and width when you add a img (take the dimensions from image). You can set a fixed width and height creating layout params with fixed positive numbers: params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100); - in pixels-

Comment: Mou by putting 100,100 on my random click it open gallery but cant see imageview can i change imageview background to see it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461191/how-to-set-backgroundcolor-on-imageview-on-android