# android ImageView auto scale

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm writing an example that's called MemoryPractice. In my app I use `ImageView` to display an image. I want them to auto scale to fit in size of screen. So I use `TableLayout` to fill all `ImageView`s. In designer, it displays normally, but in run-time when I touch on `ImageView`s that changes its size and the others auto scale.
I don't want size of `ImageView` to scale. It must keep its size as designed.

What should I do?

Here's the `layout.xml`:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black_overlay"
tools:context=".TableLayout" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img16"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: your example image isnt shown. And mind showing the code you run in onTouch?

Answer (score 3):

I think this will help you:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Try this in your image view.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the screen size before you draw the image. Then you re-scale your image and finally draw the image. You can set image size depending on screen size.

Implement the screen size capture process and scaling process in the `onTouch()` method. For reference look at this:

[How to dynamically change ImageView Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397753/how-to-dynamically-change-imageview-height)